# SQL Server AlwaysOn AG Secondary Replica is not joined

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups, high-availability, sql-server-2019

I have created an Availablity Group on SQL Server 2019. I selected 2 SQL server for  Replicas but the Secondary replica has an error:

> This secondary database is not joined to the availability group. The configuration of this secondary database is incomplete. For information about how to join a secondary database to an availability group, see SQL Server Books Online.

When I want to add manually I give an error:

> An availability replica already exists...

What the problem?

Comment: Can you add more details on how you set up the AG? Did you use the wizard UI or scripts? (If scripts, can you post the commands used?) When you try to "add manually" what are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is my authentication method problem. I changed my account and it is resolved.